# How to iterate over a dict proxy in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I'm using Python's `multiprocessing.Manager` to share access to a dataset that one process will generate and others will view. However, I'm running into the problem that a dict proxy returned by `manager.dict()` doesn't support `iteritems()`.

I could iterate over `items()`, but that means constructing a new tuple of all the items in the dict, which is a large number. Is there a way to do it without constructing an intermediate list/tuple, thus using only a constant amount of extra memory?

Note: It's OK if the solution requires that the generating process pauses for the iteration.

Comment: did You considered to use `SyncManager` and register there your own proxy with `iteritems` exposed?

Comment: @oleg You can't simply expose iteritems, because the dict iterators it returns are not pickleable. That's why the default dict proxy doesn't expose it and hence the question.

Comment: I didn't say "simply" expose. :) can we use `IteratorProxy` to expose `iteritems`?

Comment: @oleg Sorry if my answer seemed dismissive. I'm sure some kind of proxy is a solution, but I don't see how I'd construct one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could iterate over `keys()` to reduce your memory footprint. You'd have to guard against keys being deleted.

Otherwise, here's an example with two different ways that will let you iterate through the items in a dict. The `iteritems()` method in this example only works from the process that creates the manager object and the child process that the manager object creates. That's because the manager object is needed to create new proxies, and other processes don't have access to it. The `iteritems2()` method works from other processes, since it doesn't rely on creating a new proxy in those processes.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import multiprocessing.managers

class mydict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        dict.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.iters = {}

    def iteritems(self):
        print "iteritems", mp.current_process()
        return dict.iteritems(self)

    def _iteritems_start(self):
        print "_iteritems_start", mp.current_process()
        i = dict.iteritems(self)
        self.iters[id(i)] = i
        return id(i)

    def _iteritems_next(self, iter_id):
        try:
            return self.iters[iter_id].next()
        except StopIteration:
            del self.iters[iter_id]
            return None

class mydict_proxy(mp.managers.DictProxy):
    def iteritems(self):
        print "iteritems proxy", mp.current_process()
        return self._callmethod("iteritems")

    def iteritems2(self):
        print "iteritems2 proxy", mp.current_process()
        iter_id = self._callmethod("_iteritems_start")
        def generator():
            while True:
                a = self._callmethod("_iteritems_next", 
                             (iter_id,))
                if a == None:
                    return
                yield a
        return generator()

    _method_to_typeid_ = { "iteritems": "Iterator" }
    _exposed_ = mp.managers.DictProxy._exposed_
    _exposed_ += ("iteritems", "_iteritems_start", "_iteritems_next")

class mymanager(mp.managers.BaseManager):
    pass
mymanager.register("mydict", mydict, mydict_proxy)
mymanager.register("Iterator", proxytype = mp.managers.IteratorProxy,
           create_method = False)

def other(d):
    for k, v in d.iteritems2():
        d[k] = v.lower()
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        d[k] = ord(v)

def main():
    manager = mymanager()
    manager.start()
    d = manager.mydict(list(enumerate("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP")))
    for (k, v) in d.iteritems():
        print k, v
    proc = mp.Process(target = other, args = (d,))
    proc.start()
    proc.join()
    for (k, v) in d.iteritems():
        print k, v

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note that while this code may be more memory efficient, it's probably going to be a heck of a lot slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SyncManager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager) class to register your own types. Then you can implement methods on that type, e.g. for getting only a limited number of items from a dict.

Here's an example to get you started:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import managers


class TakerDict(dict):
    """Like a dict, but allows taking a limited number of items."""

    def take(self, items=1):
        """Take the first `items` items."""
        return [item for _, item in zip(range(items), self.items())]


# NOTE: add other dict methods to the tuple if you need them.
TakerProxy = managers.MakeProxyType('TakerProxy', ('take',))

managers.SyncManager.register('taker', TakerDict, TakerProxy)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    taker = manager.taker()
    # in other processes, use e.g. taker.take(5)
```

Thus, to limit memory usage, you would have to call the manager process repeatedly to get the next batch of elements.

To do that, however, your dict would have to support indexing (so you can resume from a specific offset). Since you don't have access to the underlying order of elements in a dict, you would probably be better off using a list instead (e.g. `manager.list()`). Then in your subprocesses, ask for the `len()` of the list, and index by a slice to get a batch of the appropriate size — you don't need to register any proxy type for that.

Comment: Aren't you basically just implementing the "convert to list" workaround I mentioned in the question, but in a somewhat complicated way? This doesn't really solve the problem (of memory use from needing a list too) at all.

Comment: Well, this does convert the data to list in the end, so it does come with the memory overhead. It just does so in chunks so you don't get that much overhead. I don't *think* it would  perform worse than an `IteratorProxy` approach, but I haven't measured anything.

Comment: Except it doesn't actually do the chunks: *"To do that, however, your dict would have to support indexing (so you can resume from a specific offset)."*

Comment: You're right. I see now how this doesn't actually solve your problem (unless of course you change your data type from dict to list, which might not be ideal). — Should I remove this answer or is it still useful?

Comment: I think it could help someone who comes along find a real solution.

Answer (score -2):

`iteritems()` is for a <del>list</del> dict. You could use a for loop. Or you could say `sorted()` which will return keys in a sorted list and then iterate over that list and do `dict[key]`. Hope that helps. If there is any better way. DO share with me. I am dying to know.